# One more char ">" was added to the last

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have an asp.net web form. I used Gridview to display the table from a database. There are one of field might have a long no white-space string. Therefore I used wrap-word.
The markup code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" BorderColor="YellowGreen"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProbId"
                PageSize="30" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" Visible="true">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProbId" HeaderText="ProbId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
                        SortExpression="ProbId" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProbDesc" HeaderText="ProbDesc" SortExpression="ProbDesc" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ABCD" ItemStyle-Width="75px" SortExpression="ABCD">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="width: 75px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; word-wrap: break-word;">
                                <%# Eval("ABCD")%>
                                ></div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now the wrap-word does work, however the displayed context is wrong. Each string was add a ">" at the last.
Please see the image:
[image]

You see that '648.04' becomes '648.04' >

"None" becomes "None >".

Thanks for help.

Comment: In the template field ABCD inside the item template, you have a div which evals ABCD, and it seems like you do have an extra greater than sign there `>` before closing the `</div>`

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question. LOL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div style="width: 75px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; word-wrap: break-word;">
        <%# Eval("ABCD")%>
    ></div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

There's an extra `>` just before the `div` closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
 <div style="width: 75px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; word-wrap: break-word;">
 <%# Eval("ABCD")%>
 ></div>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

To this

```
 <ItemTemplate>
 <div style="width: 75px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; word-wrap: break-word;">
 <%# Eval("ABCD")%>
 ></div>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

You have extra '>' before closing div